# Implementing ternary relationship in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have four tables.entities,

1. User
2. Project
3. Role
4. UserProjectRole

My scenario or relation is, In one project, one user has many roles.
I am confused to map relationships in above hibernate entities.
Need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the relationship of UserProjectRole with other entities. OR usage of UserProjectRole table?

Comment: I will use it to store which User has which role in which project. For Example, User "A" has role "ScrumMaster" in Project "P".

Comment: Can a user have multiple roles in a project? e.g. User A is both a scrummaster and a developer in project P?

Comment: Yes, There can be. This is a part of user story I got from stakeholders. I am just writing what they have described to me. "A user can play multiple role like "scrum master" as well as "developer".

Comment: Can a user work on multiple projects at a time? (partial allocation)

Comment: Yes, User can work on multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement a so called ternary relationship with Hibernate, either leveraging a ["simple" map](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ternary) or implementing the association using an intermediate entity / table. Your use cases decide which is the right one. It depends on how the data is stored and how (often) you are going to read it. Also reporting is an important use case.

If you want to allow many user - project - role combinations a map (e.g. on the user entity) is not really suitable because your key would probably be either the project or the role and a key could only appear once. Nevertheless every relation entry should be unique in your system, so in this case I would tend to the intermediate table with at least some unique constraint.

The "quick and dirty" way would be an entity like:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"user_id", "project_id", "role_id"}))
public class UserProjectRoleSimple {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    private Project project;
    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;

    // you also need constructors, getters, equals, hashcode and stuff

}
```

Another (the better) approach would be to use your relation object identifier as composite key. This is a little more verbose but you don't need an additional surrogate key so your join table is cleaner.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;

@Entity
@Immutable
public class UserProjectRole {

    protected UserProjectRole() {
    }

    public UserProjectRole(final User user, final Project project, final Role role) {
        this.userProjectRoleId = new UserProjectRoleId(user, project, role);
        this.user = user;
        this.project = project;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    protected UserProjectRoleId userProjectRoleId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Project project;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Role role;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    @Embeddable
    static class UserProjectRoleId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7994974851694559677L;

        @NotNull
        private Long userId;
        @NotNull
        private Long projectId;
        @NotNull
        private Long roleId;

        protected UserProjectRoleId() {
        }

        protected UserProjectRoleId(final User user, final Project project, final Role role) {
            this.userId = user.getId();
            this.projectId = project.getId();
            this.roleId = role.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((projectId == null) ? 0 : projectId.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((roleId == null) ? 0 : roleId.hashCode());
            result = prime * result + ((userId == null) ? 0 : userId.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            UserProjectRoleId other = (UserProjectRoleId) obj;
            if (projectId == null) {
                if (other.projectId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!projectId.equals(other.projectId))
                return false;
            if (roleId == null) {
                if (other.roleId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!roleId.equals(other.roleId))
                return false;
            if (userId == null) {
                if (other.userId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!userId.equals(other.userId))
                return false;
            return true;
        } 

    }

}
```

That mapping is also really simple, the only extraordinary parts are the `@JoinColumn(name = "...Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)` additions. With that you can use your mapped entity (for navigation purposes) without storing it twice.